# Can using a class method cause unbounded memory growth using ARC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

In my app I have a class method on a utility class that allocates a new UILabel and returns it:

```
+ (UILabel *)createLbl:(CGRect)lblRect boldFont:(BOOL)boldFont lblTxtColor:(UIColor *)txtColor lblFontSize:(float)fontSize {
    UILabel *label        = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.frame           = lblRect;
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.font            = boldFont
                            ? [GlobalUtility getDefaulBoldFontForSize:fontSize]
                            : [GlobalUtility getDefaulFontForSize:fontSize];
    label.textColor       = [txtColor copy];
    label.textAlignment   = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.lineBreakMode   = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    label.numberOfLines   = 0;
    return label;
}

+ (UIFont*)getDefaulBoldFontForSize:(float)size {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return [UIFont fontWithName:NSLocalizedString(@"Lato-Bold", nil) size:size];
    }
}

+ (UIFont*)getDefaulFontForSize:(float)size {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return [UIFont fontWithName:NSLocalizedString(@"Lato-Regular", nil) size:size];
    }
}
```

I profiled my app with Allocations in Instruments, and whenever call `createLbl:boldFont:lblTxtColor` we get unbounded memory growth. It is almost as if, because it's a class method, it's adding extra retain counts to things. I tried wrapping it in `@autoreleasepool` to no effect.

There are a number of other class methods where we allocate a string or such inside the class method and in those cases also we are seeing this growth.

Is there a reason why allocating inside a class method would lead to unbounded growth? Does the class retain a reference to the allocated UILabel in the example?

---

Edit: below is an example of the code we call this from. It updates a status indicator on the navigation bar.

```
- (void)showIndicatorWithNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {
    /* show a little number with how many sync items remain in the current sync cycle */
    NSString *bundleID = [GlobalUtility getAppBundleID];
    NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[notification.object intValue]];
    if ([bundleID isEqualToString:BETA_BUNDLEID]) {
        UILabel *syncCount;

        /* Re-use the existing label if it exists */
        NSArray *subviews = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.customView.subviews;
        for(UIView *view in subviews) {
            if([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
                if(view.tag == 66) {
                    syncCount = (UILabel *)view;
                }
            }
        }

        /* Otherwise create it */
        if(syncCount == nil) {
            syncCount = [PDXControl createLbl:CGRectMake(60, 40-15, 15, 15) boldFont:NO lblTxtColor:[UIColor whiteColor] lblFontSize:10.0f];
            syncCount.tag = 66;
            [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.customView addSubview:syncCount];
        }
        syncCount.text = text;
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.customView setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the code where you're calling the class method.

Comment: ARC uses Cocoa conventions about method names to reason about memory management. The [`get` prefix has a specific meaning](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-1004202), and [`create` is significant in a function name, in the context of CFTypes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029). These shouldn't have a direct effect here, but you should be aware.

Comment: @JoshCaswell thanks for that tip. If a method is named "get" which returns a value, does that encourage ARC to behave differently regarding the retain count of that value than it would otherwise? I realize it does in the case of methods named "create" (sometimes?) but it's unclear how to tell when or if that is happening. There are a lot of methods they have in this code (which I'm responsible for cleaning up) which are named "getSomething" and which are void functions. However some of the class methods (and some non-class ones) are named "get.." and return a value, that ends up over-retained.

Comment: @MarcusAdams OK I added an example for ya.

Comment: Actually, it looks like ARC doesn't have any special handling for `get...` methods: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#method-families ARC will make sure that the return value is valid across the return, potentially by adding a retain inside and a release outside. If this were MRR, the private auto release pool in those `get...` methods would cause the `UIFont` object to be invalid before it got back to the caller. That rule hasn't changed under ARC; even if it does end up working, it's by accident. You should remove the `@autorelease{}` for sure.

Comment: I'm not so sure about that. I do wonder if it's not expecting a non-retained property to get returned by the get, and then inserting an extra retain where it shouldn't... because that's what I'm seeing happen. I will do some more experimenting but I think I will add `NS_RETURNS_RETAINED` to the header for those methods just to be clear for clang.

Comment: I don't see an issue in the code that you've posted.

Comment: @JoshCaswell So, here's my hypothesis after seeing a lot of memory issues go away after removing "get" keyword from as many method names as I could. Apple says "The Get Rule" is, "If you receive an object from any Core Foundation function other than a creation or copy function—such as a Get function—you do not own it and cannot be certain of the object’s life span." In turn, Clang's ARC documentation says ivars of non-synthesized getters "will not be automatically released", so I suspect when ARC sees "get.." method name, it assumes the returned value is unsafe & inserts an extra **retain**.

Comment: However if the value already has a retain count of 1, now it will have two. I should note that I traced this down to `obj_c::sidetable_retain` which tells may give a clue to some of you as to the nature of what's going on here. I suspected the problem might be related to using class methods with "get.." in the method name to return values to a singleton, creating a sort of perfect storm for ARC. Some genius like Mike Ash could probably tell us.